# Java android - change brightness for my application

Tags: java, android, brightness

how can i change application brightness? I know this method

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = (value);
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

BUT, this method can change just view (activity) brightness, I want to change brightness for all activities in my application. How can I do it?

Also I do not want to change system brightness manually!! So just brightness for all activities JUST in my application.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do that. I would save the brightness value the device is on when the user launches the app, then set the brightness to whatever value you want, and reset the brightness to the initial saved value when the user exits the app.

Comment: aaaa it occurred to me too, but i thought it would be easier way than save settings & restart app

Comment: The problem here is "when the user exits the app" - there is no guarantee that you know. Your app could be killed without a chance to change things back. It's better if you set window params everywhere - e.g. put the window param part into a base `Activity` and extend all your activites from that one.

Comment: I use this way - in settings activity I just set the values into settings class & save it into a cfg file... in main activity I just inicialize the settings class again & load cfg file & set the values as defaults - in this way everytime i create the mainactivity this values will be used